# parked domain gives me SSL errors

Tags: wordpress, ssl

i build wordpress website in 000webhostapp 
and tried to put parked domain from freenom website 
then got an error when i tried to see my website throught 
https or Http 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEUY4.png)

i tried plugin SSL but not usefull also 
also changed the url from setting tab also not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. You cannot just point your domain to their server since there is no certificate matching you domain there. And with the free hosting their will be no way to provide your own certificate. From 000webhostapp's [Web Hosting FAQ & Knowledge Base](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/ssl-certificates-do-you-support-ssl-31):

> **SSL certificates, do you support SSL?**
>   We do not support SSL certificates and https secure connections.
>   However you can upgrade your account and enjoy full benefits of SSL

Comment: any alternative way to fix this issue manually using configs in wordpress or editing in .htaccess code

Comment: @MansourAhmed:  If the server does not provide a certificate for the name the browser will abandon the TLS handshake before the HTTP requests is sent which means before any configurations from wordpress or .htaccess will be consulted. You might try to make use of Cloudflare Free SSL to make your server accessible by HTTPS.